# Make multiple lines TODOs at once in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm new to emacs and org-mode and this seems like it should be easy but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Let's say I'm typing a todo list in `~/my_todo.org` and i type up something like this:

```
* item 1
* item 2
** item 2.1
** item 2.2
* item 3
```

and now I want to make all of them TODOs. I could move the cursor on to each line and do `C-c C-t` but then I have to do that a bunch of times. Is there a way to select all of the lines and apply something like `C-c C-t` to each one to get something like

```
* TODO item 1
* TODO item 2
** TODO item 2.1
** TODO item 2.2
* TODO item 3
```

in one fell swoop?

Comment: did you try macros? F3 C-c C-t C-n F4, then C-u 5 F5.

Comment: Check out Magnar's `multiple-cursors` library and watch the Emacs Rocks video on that subject.  It is a cannot-live-without library, in my opinion.

Comment: @Hellseher Thank you, i was not familiar with emacs macros. That sounds very promising

Comment: @lawlist will do, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this, with a caveat, by defining your own org function. Something like so:

```
(defun my/mark-todo-in-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((scope (if mark-active 'region 'tree))
        (state (org-fast-todo-selection)))
    (org-map-entries (lambda () (org-todo state)) nil scope)))
```

This has a few behaviors that are nice:

1. It will prompt you for a `TODO` state to use, meaning it respects custom TODO keyword lists. (Also meaning you can mark the entire subtree with whatever state you're in the mood for.)
2. If you select a region manually, everything in it gets marked with the TODO state you select.
3. If you don't mark a region manually, it will operate on the subtree under point.

**However**: the caveat is, everything will be marked with the same keyword. This function is fairly naive -- pick one state, map entries, *boom*, done.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll accept it as soon as I've had a chance to try it

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't always work for nested TODOs. I think the top-level one is attempted to be updated first but can't because of its subitems.

Comment: fixed by letting `(org-enforce-todo-dependencies nil)` as well, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64212/30278