# Close org todo with all subtasks

Tags: org-mode, todo

I have a task with multiple subitems in different states, and I would like to have a binding to switch the task and all its subtasks to the same state (DONE). I know that I can [ignore state blocking](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html), but that isn't what I want.

Do I have to iterate over all the subtasks for that, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the function from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38588) to a similar question, which works fantastically and even respects selections :)

```
(defun org-todo-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((scope (if mark-active 'region 'tree))
        (state (org-fast-todo-selection))
        (org-enforce-todo-dependencies nil))
    (org-map-entries (lambda () (org-todo state)) nil scope)))
```